# Python requests.json() возвращает строку, вместо json

Tags: python, json, django, requests

Почему json() возвращает мне строку? Какой от него вообще тогда смысл? Разве он не должен возвращать объект json?

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/bots/dialogs/get/bots/tokens'
x = requests.post(url).json()
print(x) # [{"model": "bot_manager.bot", "token": 13}, {"model": "bot_manager.bot", "token": 13444}, ]
print(type(x)) # <class 'str'>
```

Ответ на post-запрос

```
data = serializers.serialize("json", Bot.objects.all()) 
return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Comment: Раз возвращает строку, значит, Вам в ответе пришла json-строка.

Comment: What? Я ничего не понял. Как мне json то получить?

Comment: json.loads(x) тоже не помогает, все равно str

Comment: Как вы отвечаете на post-запрос?

Comment: data = serializers.serialize("json", Bot.objects.all())
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)

Comment: Прочтите [пост](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40483919/5894542)

Comment: Даже я, не знающий Django, вижу, что Вы сначала сериализуете объект в строку, затем эту же строку опять сериализуете в другую строку. Вам дали ссылку на хороший пост. В вашем случае будет просто `return JsonResponse(Bot.objects.all(), safe=False)` (не знаю, что такое `safe`, возможно, тоже не нужно).

Comment: @МихаилМуругов насколько я вижу по тому посту, `safe` защищает от ошибки, которая здесь и случилась.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable, нельзя просто так взять объект модели и впихнуть его в json response без сериализации

Comment: Это уже особенности бекенда, которых Вы нам не привели. Главное, что Вы поняли, что ошибка там. Возможно, там есть методы, позволяющие получить Вашу структуру в виде словаря, а не `QuerySet` (повторюсь, с джангой не знаком).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На основе [поста](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40483919/5894542), предложенного в комментариях.

`JsonResponse` берет `dict` и возвращает json-строку для передачи в запросах.

В вашем случае, вы даете `JsonResponse` уже json-строку и за счет `safe=False` **не** получаете ошибку об этом.

```
TypeError: In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False
```

Измените ответ на post-запрос, например, следующим способом

```
data = serializers.serialize("json", Bot.objects.all()) 
return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Возможно это не сработает, поскольку я не знаком с `django`. Но причина выдачи строки вместо json-формата очевидна.